# Using Sprites in extjs

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, sprite

I'm currently working on a project where we recieved all our icons in 1 sprite file. I have never ever used sprites (and i'm pretty new to extjs)
I cannot find a decent example of how to transform the following code (which uses 1 upload.png) into using a spritefile (icons.png)

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    cls: 'tasks-icon-column-header tasks-upload-column-header',
    width: 24,
    icon: 'images/upload.png',
    iconCls: 'x-hidden',
    tooltip: 'Upload',
    menuDisabled: true,
    sortable: false
    handler: Ext.bind(me.handleUploadClick, me)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define class in your css file and define the background image and position of your icon in sprite. For example, if you have icons like [this](http://start.ubuntu.com/12.04/sprite.png), do something like below to define your class and show only google icon:

```
.google_icon {
    background:url(http://start.ubuntu.com/12.04/sprite.png) -10px -310px;
    height:38px;
}​
```

and use this class in your code like this:

```
iconCls: 'google_icon',
```

you also need to remove this line:

```
icon: 'images/upload.png'
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Doing so I have a problem with background-position: center center; that sits in the .x-menu-item-icon. How did you solve this?